# javascript inside partial doesn't load anymore under angular 1.2

Tags: angularjs

Since my update to angular 1.2, I'm having issues loading javascript inside partials (loading was working perfectly under angular 1.0.8).

Please note I'm using yeoman for my project.
Javascript calls are working inside index.html, but won't load inside partials.

Here is an exemple (also tried angular-seed) :

- git clone https://github.com/angular/angular-seed.git
- partial1.html update to include javascript

Code partial1.html :

```
<p>This is the partial for view 1.</p>
<script>
alert("view 1");
</script>
```

Alert won't be called. Neither in partial2.html if you try to add js scripts.

Is it a new feature or a bug ?

Is there any way to include javascript code inside partial under angular 1.2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my javascript to work via Directive :

```
angular.directive('jsSidebar' , function() {
   return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

            // put jquery code or javascript

        }
   }
});
```

Just Add this code in your partial :

```
<div js-sidebar></div>
```